# How to pass variable from javascript to java BakingBean

Tags: java, javascript, parameter-passing, jdeveloper

I am trying to pass a variable from a Javascript method (which is written in jspx) page to a Java BakingBean.

Here is the Javascript code:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    function OnSave() {
    alert("The signature you have taken is the following data: " + SigPlus1.SigString);
    }
    </SCRIPT>
```

of course, this method will be called after the user presses the save button, defined as follows:

```
<INPUT id="submit1" name="Save" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="OnSave()"/>
```

As you can see this Javascript will alert the result to the user. ***Instead I want to pass the object (`SigPlus1`) to a Java Bean.***

I am using ADF technology with JDveloper 11.1.2.3

Comment: Is this just a raw servlet?  If so, you would need to post the form, then in your `doGet()` and or `doPost()`, you would typically read in the values from the HttpServletResponse object.

Comment: Pass your variable value through hidden field. That will be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

This paper has this covered:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/1-2011-javascript-302460.pdf
You need to use the adfCustomEvent JS method